# how do i use the relative path to the scripts folder in my asp .net / c# project code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, path, relative-path

this question should be relatively simple and shouldnt even require much explanation i dont think, here goes:

my website is executing a batch file using the Process object which requires a path to the .bat file of course

i will be housing my site on multiple servers therefore i dont want to give an absolute path i want to just use a relative path within my project (for example use the scripts folder automatically generated by visual studio when i made my project)

i just am not sure exactly how to reference that file within the code once its in the scripts folder.

here is my current code for referencing my .bat:

```
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\e\\Desktop\\Test_Bat_Thing";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\e\\Desktop\\Test_Bat_Thing\\test.bat";
```

which works perfectly. but i want it to be something along the lines of

```
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ".\\scripts";
p.StartInfo.FileName = ".\\scripts\\test.bat";
```

please help! thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = this.Server.MapPath("test.bat")
```

Comment: "the system cannot find the file specified" is what I get trying that. also i must make sure to set the working directory since my bat files calls some EXEs sitting in the same folder as it

Comment: I don't know exactly where your batch files, you will need to modify the above line to refer to the actual virtual path. I think you will need to put your batch files in a specific folder in your root so that you can correctly refer to when calling Server.MapPath

Comment: i am putting the files in a folder inside the "Scripts" folder that visual studio makes by default when you start a new project

Comment: Then, this should work? p.StartInfo.FileName = this.Server.MapPath("Scripts\test.bat")

Comment: ok everybody here is the final answer to this problem that did work: p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = this.Server.MapPath("Scripts\\Test_Bat_Thing");
p.StartInfo.FileName = this.Server.MapPath("Scripts\\Test_Bat_Thing\\test.bat"); Test_Bat_Thing is a folder I created inside of the Scripts folder. this is tested and works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try out using  `"~/"` (Web Root Operator) as reference to the site web root folder.

Also you can convert Virtual Path into a Physical Path using:

```
string rootPath = Server.MapPath("~");
```

---

Web Root Operator:

> ASP.NET includes the Web application root operator (~), which you can
>   use when specifying a path in server controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~
>   operator to the root of the current application. You can use the ~
>   operator in conjunction with folders to specify a path that is based
>   on the current root.

For more details see on MSDN: [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Comment: so how do i reference the scripts folder from ~ ? everything i try doesnt work >.<

Comment: Try out `~/scripts/`. See in IIS what is WebRoot path and ensure that scripts folder is under this root path.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to reference the Desktop Path of the current user, you can use this statement

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

your code will look like

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, "\\Test_Bat_Thing\\test.bat");
```

Comment: What is Desktop Path considering that we have a web application?

Comment: The question was about paths relative to web app root.

Comment: i think u misinterpreted the question im trying to NOT use that path. all i want is the relative path for the scripts folder to pass into the Process object p